# Buffering when serving videos on Flask app in multiple devices

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, html5-video

I have created a prototype of a website serving two videos via a Flask application. I am currently testing them in flask's dev server but I am facing buffering issues when serving over 3 devices (sometimes with 3 also, but change in buffer size fixed it). Here's what my code looks like:

```py
def partial_response(path, start, end=None):
    file_size = os.path.getsize(path)
    if(end is None):
        end = start + BUFF_SIZE - 1
    end = min(end, file_size)
    end = min(end, start + BUFF_SIZE - 1)
    length = end - start + 1

    #read file
    with open(path, 'rb') as video_file:
        video_file.seek(start)
        bytes = video_file.read(length)

    response = Response(
        bytes, 
        206, 
        mimetype=mimetypes.guess_type(path)[0],
        direct_passthrough=True
        )

    response.headers.add(
        'Content-Range', 'bytes {0}-{1}/{2}'.format(start, end, file_size)
    )

    response.headers.add(
        'Accept-Ranges', 'bytes'
    )

    return response

def get_range(req):
    range = req.headers.get('Range')
    print(range)
    m = re.match('bytes=(?P<start>\d+)-(?P<end>\d+)?', range)
    if(m):
        start = int(m.group('start'))
        end = m.group('end')
        if end is not None: 
            end = int(end)
        return [start, end]
    else:
        return [0, None]

@app.route("/two.mp4")
def two():
    return render_template('watch_video.html', video_name="two.mp4")

@app.route("/static/videos/two.mp4")
def two_video():
    start, end = get_range(request)
    print(start, end)
    return partial_response("p<ath to two.mp4>", start, end)

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Can the buffering be due to:

1. flask and its blocking API?
2. Buffer size?
3. Resource capacity of the hosting machine?
4. Router limitations?
5. Just bad code?

OR may be anything else? I need some guidance.

No of intended devices: 10 
No of test devices: 5 
Test video size: 1GB

Comment: What sort of "but I am facing buffering issues" buffering issues?

Comment: The video is taking time to load. It stops while playing for a while, then loads and then plays.

Comment: Are you hosting with the built in flask server currently? @manavGArg

Comment: yes. I am hosting it on my laptop right now and testing it on WLAN.

Comment: Take a look at this article. https://vsupalov.com/flask-web-server-in-production/  . If I am not mistaken you are running into that issue due to the fact that currently you are using the built in web server that comes with flask/python. Try hosting it using gunicorn, to see if that resolves your problem

Comment: I think it should work. Thanks! I'll try it.

Comment: @ManavGarg With gunicorn, you may also want to try `eventlet` or `gevent` worker type, see this [github issue](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-video-streaming/issues/6#issuecomment-322266339) for some info on the numbers and commands.

Comment: I am using Tornado for now. I'll switch to gunicorn if it fails me. Thanks for the headsup!